# python, selenium: ImportError: No module named options

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using selenium and I tried to import the option module from selenium in python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
```

and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\GHIE\Desktop\jeahx\kests\test2.pyw", line 2, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
ImportError: No module named options
```

from the way I see it the selenium that I have has no module named "Options"
but why? any Idea how could I fix this?
I'm on windows 7 and python 2.7
thanks

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that maybe you do not have everything installed. Maybe check this path:

```
/usr/lib/python/dist-packages/selenium
```

And make sure all the classes are in there somewhere.
If not, try uninstalling (assuming you are using pip):

```
$ sudo pip uninstall selenium
```

And then reinstall.

```
$ sudo pip install selenium
```

Now try again.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
```

If that does not work, check the documentation.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium

Comment: thanks for replying, but seems it still is the same

Comment: Check now. Try that.

Comment: Hi, I still did not try uninstalling it but I tried to navigate to the selenium folder and it just contains folders and two "dll" files, is it okay?
this is the directory that I checked "C:\Python27\selenium\webdriver\ie" that "ie" folder contains two folder named "win32" and "x64" and they both contain one "dll" file each

Comment: Did it work bro?

Comment: Delete "C:/Python27/selenium". Then reinstall. It sounds like your install failed somehow. Have you used it successfully before now?? I am here and checking your response every 10 mins. So reply whenever. Also, a up vote wouldn't kill me ;)

Comment: sorry, the connection just blown out, I deleted the folder and reinstalled again using pip and it says something like "requirements already satisfied" and hey I tried to upvote and it says "I need 15 reputation" I only have 11 right now sorry bro

Comment: To address the issue: did you use the pip uninstall command as well? It is still in pips cache. That's why. Uninstall with pip then try. As for the up vote, thanks lol I forgot about thst. Just go answer questions and ask questions a lot and you get 21 like me!! Good luck. Still available for any further questions regarding this issue.

Comment: I uninstalled it now, and when I tried to install it again it says something like "can't find the version......." I'll try to download it again

Comment: It worked!!!!!!! I downloaded the 3.7.0 tar gz the options is with me now thanks,,,,,,,,,,,, @AllAmericanProgrammer

Comment: Yup. God luck. Glad I could help.